# The import java.util.Base64 cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jsp

I am using a .jsp file and the following line gives an error

```
<%@page import="java.util.Base64"%>
```

> The import java.util.Base64 cannot be resolved

Comment: do i need any specific jar for this

Answer (score 7):

[java.util.Base64](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) was added in Java 8. Perhaps you are using an older version of Java.

Comment: i need jdk7 for some of my applications..so can i have both java 7and 8 installed in the same machine

Comment: @SamikshaSardal Yes, you can.